# Context free grammar for palindrome over ALL terminals?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I've found various examples of context-free grammars for palindromes but they all seem to hardcode the rules to be of the form "terminal Statement (same) terminal"

For example, if $T \rightarrow a | b | c$ and we wanted to generate any-length palindromes, the grammar rules would be $S \to aSa \mid bSb \mid cSc \mid T \mid \epsilon$

Is there way to make a generalized rule rather than individually listing $aSa$, $bSb$, ... for every terminal character?

Comment: I doubt it.  If you have a rule like $S\longrightarrow XSX$ then you can substitute for the two occurrences of $X$ independently, and get non-palindromes.

Comment: Yup this has been my issue. Is there notation to signify that the second X should match the first X?

Comment: Your rule $S \to T$ already does not make sense.

Comment: How so? Isn't that just saying S can go to any terminal character? Perhaps I should instead say 
T -> a | b | c ?

Comment: Exactly, it shoud be $S \to a \mid b \mid c$.

Comment: No there is not such a notation.  You can substitute, for any non-terminal, then right-hand side on any production of which said non-terminal is the right-hand side.  That's what *context-free* means.  If you say, "One can substitute $a$ for the second $X$ provided one has substituted $a$ for the first $X$", then the permitted substitutions depend on the context, don't they?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for explaining that. Would you mind if I used that to self-answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @saulspatz:

"If you say, "One can substitute a for the second X provided one has substituted a for the first X", then the permitted substitutions depend on the context, don't they?"

By nature of being context free, a general rule for such a thing is not possible. It must be explicitly specified by doing something like "aSa"